# Linear Regression using R

Tags: r

I have the following formula where I am trying to find coef1, coef2...coef5 and all of the other variables are known.

```
d ~ a + 2 * (coef1 * b1 + coef2 * b2 + coef3 * b3 + coef4 * b4 + coef5 * b5)
```

I have been solving this using nonlinear least squares (nls) like so with no problem.

```
nlsfit <- nls(d ~ a + 2 * (coef1 * b1 + coef2 * b2 + coef3 * b3 + coef4 * b4 + coef5 * b5), data=df, start=list(coef1=0, coef2=0, coef3=0, coef4=0, coef5=0))
```

However I have been told that this should be solved using linear least squares. So I have attempted to use the lm function and glm

```
lmfit <- lm(d ~ a + 2 * (coef1 * b1 + coef2 * b2 + coef3 * b3 + coef4 * b4 + coef5 * b5), data=df)


glmfit <- glm(d ~ a + 2 * (coef1 * b1 + coef2 * b2 + coef3 * b3 + coef4 * b4 + coef5 * b5), data=df, family=binomial())
```

These both return an error I believe because the dataframe doesn't have any of the coef* variables

```
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : invalid model formula in ExtractVars
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to solve this using linear least squares?

Comment: You're trying to fit two different models in `lmfit` and `glmfit`. In the latter case, you're trying to do logistic regression which dictates a logic (and data) on its own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want

```
lm(d / 2 ~ offset(a / 2) + b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5, data=df)
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to add the coefficients to the formula in R. Type `?formula` in R.

Instead, you can use this formula :

```
x=d-a
form <- x ~  b1 +  b2 +  b3 + b4 + b5
```

as you do not want to multiply your variable `a` by a coefficient.